# How to select a data slice for a specific date from a SQL SERVER database tables which track changes on the row level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

All tables in the database has a Date column named EffectiveDate.

Data is imported into the database using a logic which detects and inserts changed records only.

Let us assume 5 imports happened between 1/1/2014 and 5/1/2014

So Table A has:

```
EffectiveDate   id1     column1  column2
--------------  ----   -------- --------
01/01/2014      1       ABC      123
02/01/2014      1       ABC      999
05/01/2014      1       XXX      999
01/01/2014      2       CCCC     555
03/01/2014      2       CCCC     444
04/01/2014      2       DDDD     444
01/01/2014      3       xxxxx     333
```

and Table B has

```
EffectiveDate   id2    column1  column2
--------------  ----- -------- --------
01/01/2014      1     ZZZZ     AAAAA
03/01/2014      1     ZZZZ     AABBB
01/01/2014      2     TTTT     AAAAA
05/01/2014      2     TTTT     AABBB
```

Now The task is to create 3 set of views for all tables:

- The first set is to give the Effective data as of current date
- The second set is to give latest data
- The third set is to give the data changes after today date (just next changes not the latest)

Consideration:

All views should return only one row for each id with applicable effective date.

If effective date is not available then the maximum effective date in the table less then the requested effective date should be used.

I was able to come up with solution for the Effective and Latest views but not for the third set of views (Next changes)

Any idea how to address this?

Comment: Can you show the desired results for the data in your question?

Comment: Given today is 03/01/2014 the next view for table A sould return the following results

Comment: Given today is 03/01/2014 the next view for table A sould return the following results 3 rows: ids (1,2,3) and effective dates (02/01/2014, 03/01/2014, 01/01/2014) respectively.  Sorry for the bad formating as I am responding using the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Row_Number function to get this. For each id, the first future row (whatever that means...) will have a row_number of 1.

```
with RowNumbers as
(select
id1,
effectivedate,
row_number() over (partition by id1 order by effectivedate) as RowNumber
from
a
where
effectivedate > getdate()
)
select
a.*
from
A
inner join RowNumbers
    on a.id1 = Rownumbers.id1
    and rownumbers.rownumber = 1
    and a.effectivedate = rownumbers.effectivedate
```

[SQL Fidldle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b270a/14)

Comment: This is will not return all records, just add the following record to table A     ('2013-12-31 19:00:00', 3, 'oldd', 123)  Notice that your code will only return records with id 1 and 2 not the old data with id 3.  Check the modified script here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9c13/1/0)

Comment: @Alobidat, there is no row for ID 3 that is after today's date, which was your requirement.

Comment: Effective stay effective if no new record introduced. Base data my never change for some records and since the challenge.